# grep regex - how do I match same character pairs?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Say I have the following string:

```
blah blah blah \the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\ blah blah blah \ \\ \\ \\ \ foobar \ a\\b\\c\\ \
```

and I want to match the following 3 matches using grep:

```
\the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\
```

and

```
\ \\ \\ \\ \
```

and

```
\ a\\b\\c\\ \
```

to do this I need a way to pair '\\' as to only end the match when there is a single closing '\' that isn't part of a pair.

so far I have this:

```
echo $string | grep -oP '\\((?!\\).)*\\'
```

edit: I managed to get it working in the regex101 environment:

```
\\((?!\\).|(([\\]{2})+))+\\
```

https://regex101.com/r/wC2cF1/13

but it's still giving me the same result in grep perl

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Do you want to match whatever is inside blackslashes \ \ ??

Comment: yes, including other backslashes in a way that "\ \\ \\ \\ \ foobar \ a\\ b\\ c\\ \" would yield 2 results: (\ \\ \\ \\ \\) and (\ a\\ b\\ c\\ \\).

Comment: I think this works \\(\w|\s|\\{2})*\\. Try out here - https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/1

Comment: regex101 is practically useless for determining how any given command line tool will interpret a given regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63198110/1745001) solution is simpler and better than the answer below. But beware that its behaviour is different on a string `\\\xy\`, for example.

---

Using GNU utilities:

```
sed 's/\\\\/\x00/g' file | grep -ao '\\[^\\]*\\' | sed 's/\x00/\\\\/g'
```

---

- The first `sed` replaces each double backslash (`\\`) with a null character (highly unlikely to occur in the original data to be processed).
- The `grep` captures and prints the characters between matching single backslashes (`\`). The GNU specific `-a` option allows to process a binary file as if it were a text file since the stream may contain null characters at this point. With the GNU specific `-o` option, `grep` prints  only the matching parts of the line, each one on a separate output line.
- The last `sed` restores the double backslashes by replacing each null   character with a `\\`.

Please notice that those are highly GNU specific.

---

Test:

```
$ line='blah blah blah \the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\ blah blah blah \ \\ \\ \\ \ foobar \ a\\b\\c\\ \'
$ sed 's/\\\\/\x00/g' <<< "$line" | grep -ao '\\[^\\]*\\' | sed 's/\x00/\\\\/g'
\the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\
\ \\ \\ \\ \
\ a\\b\\c\\ \
```

Comment: Not only is a NUL character highly unlike to occur in a text file, it **cannot** occur in a text file because by definition a **text** file does not include NUL characters. That also means that what any given text-based tool like `grep` does with input that contains NULs is undefined behavior so YMMV with whatever any tool might do with the output of that first `sed` command.

Comment: @EdMorton That's why I wrote "those are highly GNU specific".

Comment: "Highly GNU specific" doesn't mean that a given tool that handles undefined behavior a given way in any given release will handle it the same way in any other given release or anything else. GNU grep has an option `-z` to define how it will handle NUL bytes if present but if you don't use that option then what GNU grep will do with NULs in the input is simply undefined and if it does what you want in release n that doesn't mean it'll do what you want in release n+1.

Comment: @EdMorton The `-a` option of `grep` process a binary file as if it were text. This is documented in the manual page of GNU `grep`.

Comment: If that's what you're counting on to handle NULs in the input then just update your answer to say that as just saying it's GNU specific doesn't address it and add to the 2nd sed whatever the GNU sed option is to also handle binary input (`-b`?) You don't need the `-E`s on your sed commands btw, they aren't doing anything that requires EREs.

Comment: If you wanted to not use NULs you could instead do `sed 's/@/@A/g; s/=/@B/g; s/\\\\/=/g' file | grep -o '\\[^\\]*\\' | sed 's/=/\\\\/g; s/@B/=/g; s/@A/@/g'` but of course [none of this is necessary anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63198110/1745001).

Comment: @EdMorton I've never had an issue with handling binary data with GNU `sed`. In GNU `sed`, the `-b` option is ineffective unless the operating system makes a distinction between text and binary streams. Since I've never used `sed` on such a system, I don't know its behaviour regarding to the null characters in the input, with or without `-b` option, on those systems. You're right about the `-E`, it's just an habit. Ryszard Czech's solution is simple and elegant. But it behaves different than my solution given the input \\\xy\. I don't know which output is intended by the OP in this case.

Comment: Ah, right because given 3 backslashes at the front your script will replace the first 2 with NUL instead of the last 2, i.e. ```\\\xy\``` would become ```<nul>\xy\``` instead of ```\<nul>xy\```. I suspect that's undesirable but it'd be nice if the OP had included that case in their example so we'd know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
text='blah blah blah \the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\ blah blah blah \ \\ \\ \\ \ foobar \ a\\b\\c\\ \'
echo "$text" | grep -oE '\\([^\\]|\\\\)+\\'
```

Output:

```
\the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\
\ \\ \\ \\ \
\ a\\b\\c\\ \
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU grep then [@RyszardCzech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63198110/1745001) is a good solution, otherwise using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/\\\\/,RS)
    while ( match($0,/\\[^\\]*\\/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(RS,"\\\\",tgt)
        print tgt
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
\the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\
\ \\ \\ \\ \
\ a\\b\\c\\ \
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the core [`Text::Balanced`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/Text/Balanced.html) module to extract the string:

```
$ perl -MText::Balanced=extract_delimited -nE '$text = extract_delimited($_, q/\\/, qr/^[^\\]*/, q/\\/); say $text' input.txt
\the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\
```

Answer (score 0):

With echo grep and tail...

```
string='blah blah blah \the rain in sp\\\\ain moves mainly\\ on the p\\lain\\\\\ blah blah blah \ \\ \\ \\ \ foobar \ a\\b\\c\\ \'

echo ${string} | grep -o -E "([ \]{1,2}[ a-z]{0,2}[ \]{0,2}){1,4}" | tail -n2 | grep -o -E "[abc \]{1,32}"
```

Puts out...

```
 \ \\ \\ \\ \ 
 \ a\\b\\c\\ \
```

`grep -E` means: Using an extended regular expression